# match a price amount after a particular substring

Tags: ruby, regex

Considering this string:

```
Looking for a front-end developer who can fix a bug on my Wordpress site. The header logo disappeared after I updated some plugins.  \n\nI have tried disabling all plugins but it didn't help.Budget: $25\nPosted On: May 06, 2016 16:29 UTCCategory: Web, Mobile &amp; Software Dev &gt; Web DevelopmentSkills:        WordPress            Country: Denmarkclick to apply
```

I'd like to retrieve the price value after the string `Budget:`. I have a number of string all with the same pattern (price right after the "Budget:" string)

I tried `/\$[\d.]+/` to extract any price amount but that would take any price amount in the string not only the one following `Budget:`

How can I accomplish that ?

Comment: [`/Budget(.*)$/`](https://regex101.com/r/wZ2gP9/1)?

Comment: `str.match(/Budget: (\$[\d.]+)/)[1]`?

Comment: That's a good start @Shafizadeh :). However i'd need to capture only the price string after `Budget:`. In this example it's $25 but it could be $1000 or $10,000 or even $100.54.

Comment: @Cyzanfar Well I don't know English very well, is there any synonym for *"price"* word? are you trying to get the number of characters that are after `Budget:` ?

Comment: No I am trying to get the dollar amount RIGHT after `Budget:`. For example:
`help.Budget: $25\nPosted` i'd like to extract `$25`

Comment: @Dogbert that did not work. Is there a typo in your regex ?

Comment: @Cyzanfar Then try [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/wZ2gP9/2) and `$1` is containing what you need.

Comment: @Shafizadeh unfortunately that doesn't work because it doesn't take into account numbers that can be of this format: $10,000

Comment: @Shafizadeh that works great thanks :) متشکرم

Comment: @Cyzanfar I'm glad I could help (also maybe [this](https://regex101.com/r/wZ2gP9/4) would be more better in your case). btw I enjoyed of listening "thank" in Persian from an English person `:-)`

Comment: @Shafizadeh I am Persian also :)

Comment: @Cyzanfar Oh kidding? So why have you chosen US in your profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
r = /
    \b          # match a word break
    [Bb]        # match "B" or "b"
    udget:      # match string
    \s+\$       # match one or more spaces followed by a dollar sign
    \K          # discard all matches so far
    \d{1,3}     # match between one or three digits
    (?:\,\d{3}) # match a comma followed by three digits in a non-capture group
    *           # perform the preceding match zero or more times
    (?:\.\d\d)  # match a period followed by two digits in a non-capture group
    ?           # make the preceding match optional
    /x          # free-spacing regex definition mode

"Some text Budget: $25\nsome more text"[r]            #=> "25"
"Some text Budget: $25.42\nsome more text"[r]         #=> "25.24"
"Some text Budget: $25,642,328\nsome more text"[r]    #=> "25,642,328"
"Some text Budget: $25,642,328.01\nsome more text"[r] #=> "25,642,328.01"
```

This is actually not quite right because

```
"Some text Budget: $25,64,328.01\nsome more text"[r]  #=> "25"
```

should return `nil`. Unfortunately, the fix calls for major surgery:

```
r = /
    \b              # match a word break
    [Bb]            # match "B" or "b"
    udget:          # match string
    \s+\$           # match 1 or more spaces followed by a dollar sign
    \K              # discard all matches so far
    \d{1,3}         # match between 1 and 3 digits
    (?:             # begin a non-capture group
      (?![\,\d])    # match a comma or digit in a negative lookahead
      |             # or
      (?:           # begin a non-capture group
        (?:\,\d{3}) # match a comma followed by 3 digits in a non-capture group
        +           # perform preceding match 1 or more times
      )             # end non-capture group
    )               # end non-capture group
    (?:\.\d\d)      # match a period followed by 2 digits in a non-capture group
    ?               # make the preceding match optional
    /x

"Some text Budget: $25\nsome more text"[r]            #=> "25"
"Some text Budget: $25.42\nsome more text"[r]         #=> "25.24"
"Some text Budget: $25,642,328\nsome more text"[r]    #=> "25,642,328"
"Some text Budget: $25,642,328.01\nsome more text"[r] #=> "25,642,328.01"
"Some text Budget: $25,64,328.01\nsome more text"[r]  #=> nil
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Cary. Tell me, what does your regex captures that `Budget:.*?(\$[\d,.]+).*?$` doesn't except the fact that `Budget` might be written as `budget` too. Trying to understand what's the best approach (more abstract one)

Comment: It's not what my regex captures that your doesn't, it's what yours captures that mine doesn't. For example: `"Some text Budget: $.,..3..\nsome more text" =~ /.*?(\$[\d,.]+).*?$/ #=> 0; $1 #=> "$.,..3.."`, whereas `"Some text Budget: $.,..3..\nsome more text"[r] #=> nil`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def extract_budget s
  m = s.match(/Budget: \$([\d,.]+)\n/)
  if m.nil?
    nil
  else
    m.captures[0].gsub(/,/, "").to_f
  end
end
```

If `s1` is your string and `s2` is the same string but with "Budget: $25,000.53":

```
irb> extract_budget s1
=> 25.0
irb> extract_budget s2
=> 25000.53
irb> extract_budget "foo"
=> nil
```

Comment: Of course, this will also match `$,,,,` and `$00..00..00`, which may or may not be acceptable to OP.

Comment: @Jordan Good point. If OP needs to *validate* the budget strings a parser generator like http://kschiess.github.io/parslet/ may be more appropriate.

Comment: This code assumes that there will be a match, but if `match` returns nil then calling `captures` on it will result in an error.  So I think you'd want to break that line up to check for that, no?

Comment: correct, the code will break if `s2.match(/Budget: \$([\d,.]+)\n/)` returns `nil`

Comment: @Cyzanfar I assumed you'd have the code dealing with the budget wrapped in a `begin ... rescue ... end` but didn't state that assumption explicitly. I've updated the code to handle `nil` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You say the string "Budget:" doesn't change and assuming there are no decimal values, I'd use something like this:

```
/Budget:(\s*\$\d*)/
```